# Cannot substitute XWPFRun text correctly

Tags: java, apache-poi, xwpf

I'm trying to replace placeholders in a docx file. I developed the code but I found something tricky. I have a `XWPFRun` and in debug I can see that the content is

```
N ${placeholder1}/${placeholder1} of ${placeholder3}
```

But, when I use `run.getText(0)`, I obtain a substring that does not contain the third placeholder.

However, when I use `run.text()` and `run.toString()` methods I get the whole content:

```
N ${placeholder1}/${placeholder1}\t\t\t\tof ${placeholder3}
```

Now if I use the `getText(0)` method I can't replace the third placeholder, while when I tried to use the `text()` method I obtain

```
N ${placeholder1}/${placeholder1} of VALUE of ${placeholder3}`
```

```
run.setText(run.text().contains(placeholder) ?
    run.text().replace(placeholder, placeholderValue) :
    run.text(),0);
```

I use apache poi 3.17

Comment: Not bad for a first question. Try to use backticks ` rather than bold ** for code snippets and tripple-backticks ``` to introduce a code-block. If you edit your post you'll see how I reformatted it. Like this its a lot more readable. Good luck finding an answer.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65275097/apache-poi-my-placeholder-is-treated-as-three-different-runs/65289246#65289246

Comment: @AxelRichter I use apache poi 3.17

Comment: And why are you using that old version? Why not upgrading?

Comment: Just tested. My code works using final version of `apache poi 3.17` too. But in `3.17` `TextSegment` was incorrectly spelled `TextSegement`. So instead of `TextSegment foundTextSegment = null;` in `3.17` it must be `TextSegement foundTextSegment = null;`.