# The value "name" and "surname" aren't read apache poi

Tags: java, java-8, apache-poi, xwpf

My purpose is to read a file `docx` and take this text "#name#" and "#surname#" and change the value with another casual text:

This is my `docx` file: [image: docx]

I do this:

```
XWPFDocument docx = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open("..."));
  
            for (XWPFParagraph p : docx.getParagraphs()) {
                List<XWPFRun> runs = p.getRuns();
            
                if (runs != null) {
                    
                    for (XWPFRun r : runs) {
                        String text = r.getText(0);
                        if (text != null && text.startsWith("#") && text.endsWith("#")) {
                            text = text.replace("#", "new ");
                            r.setText(text, 0);
                        }
                      
                    }
                }
                
            }
            for (XWPFTable tbl : docx.getTables()) {
                   for (XWPFTableRow row : tbl.getRows()) {
                      for (XWPFTableCell cell : row.getTableCells()) {
                         for (XWPFParagraph p : cell.getParagraphs()) {
                   

          
                        for (XWPFRun r : p.getRuns()) {
                          String text = r.getText(0);
                          if (text != null && text.startsWith("#") && text.endsWith("#")) {
                            text = text.replace("#", "new ");
                            r.setText(text,0);
                          }
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
```

the problem is that my code reads all label in `docx` file  but it doesn't read the label "#surname#" and "#name". Anyone can help me?

Comment: Did you debug the text in getText(0) ? Read here in the comments of accepted answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22268898/replacing-a-text-in-apache-poi-xwpf about getText() in "runs".

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65275097/apache-poi-my-placeholder-is-treated-as-three-different-runs/65289246#65289246.

Comment: yeah the problem is there, when I do r.getText(0) the value is not never "#surname#" or "#name"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your screenshot it looks like the "#name#" and "#suremane#" are not in the document body directly but in a drawing (a text-box for example or a shape). Such elements are not covered by `XWPFDocument.getParagraphs` or `.getTables` or any other high level method in `apache poi`. So your main problem will be that the paragraphs which contain your text simply are not traversed by your code.

The only way to get really all paragraphs out of the documents body is using a `XmlCursor` which selects all `w:p` elements from the `XML` directly.

The code below shows that. It traverses really all `XWPFParagraphs` in documents body using a `XmlCursor` and replaces text if found.

For the replacement process I prefer the `TextSegment` replacement approach shown in [Apache POI: ${my_placeholder} is treated as three different runs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65275097/apache-poi-my-placeholder-is-treated-as-three-different-runs/65289246#65289246) already. This is necessary because, even if the containing paragraph gets traversed, the text could be separated in different text runs because of formatting, spell checking or any other strange reasons. `Microsoft Word` knows nearly infinity reasons to strangely split text into different text runs.

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.*;

import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject;
import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlCursor;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class WordReplaceTextSegment {
    
    /**
     * this methods parse the paragraph and search for the string searched.
     * If it finds the string, it will return true and the position of the String
     * will be saved in the parameter startPos.
     *
     * @param searched
     * @param startPos
     */
    static TextSegment searchText(XWPFParagraph paragraph, String searched, PositionInParagraph startPos) {
        int startRun = startPos.getRun(),
            startText = startPos.getText(),
            startChar = startPos.getChar();
        int beginRunPos = 0, candCharPos = 0;
        boolean newList = false;

        //CTR[] rArray = paragraph.getRArray(); //This does not contain all runs. It lacks hyperlink runs for ex.
        java.util.List<XWPFRun> runs = paragraph.getRuns(); 
        
        int beginTextPos = 0, beginCharPos = 0; //must be outside the for loop
        
        //for (int runPos = startRun; runPos < rArray.length; runPos++) {
        for (int runPos = startRun; runPos < runs.size(); runPos++) {
            //int beginTextPos = 0, beginCharPos = 0, textPos = 0, charPos; //int beginTextPos = 0, beginCharPos = 0 must be outside the for loop
            int textPos = 0, charPos;
            //CTR ctRun = rArray[runPos];
            CTR ctRun = runs.get(runPos).getCTR();
            XmlCursor c = ctRun.newCursor();
            c.selectPath("./*");
            try {
                while (c.toNextSelection()) {
                    XmlObject o = c.getObject();
                    if (o instanceof CTText) {
                        if (textPos >= startText) {
                            String candidate = ((CTText) o).getStringValue();
                            if (runPos == startRun) {
                                charPos = startChar;
                            } else {
                                charPos = 0;
                            }

                            for (; charPos < candidate.length(); charPos++) {
                                if ((candidate.charAt(charPos) == searched.charAt(0)) && (candCharPos == 0)) {
                                    beginTextPos = textPos;
                                    beginCharPos = charPos;
                                    beginRunPos = runPos;
                                    newList = true;
                                }
                                if (candidate.charAt(charPos) == searched.charAt(candCharPos)) {
                                    if (candCharPos + 1 < searched.length()) {
                                        candCharPos++;
                                    } else if (newList) {
                                        TextSegment segment = new TextSegment();
                                        segment.setBeginRun(beginRunPos);
                                        segment.setBeginText(beginTextPos);
                                        segment.setBeginChar(beginCharPos);
                                        segment.setEndRun(runPos);
                                        segment.setEndText(textPos);
                                        segment.setEndChar(charPos);
                                        return segment;
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    candCharPos = 0;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        textPos++;
                    } else if (o instanceof CTProofErr) {
                        c.removeXml();
                    } else if (o instanceof CTRPr) {
                        //do nothing
                    } else {
                        candCharPos = 0;
                    }
                }
            } finally {
                c.dispose();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

 static void replaceTextSegment(XWPFParagraph paragraph, String textToFind, String replacement) {
  TextSegment foundTextSegment = null;
  PositionInParagraph startPos = new PositionInParagraph(0, 0, 0);
  //while((foundTextSegment = paragraph.searchText(textToFind, startPos)) != null) { // search all text segments having text to find
  while((foundTextSegment = searchText(paragraph, textToFind, startPos)) != null) { // search all text segments having text to find

System.out.println(foundTextSegment.getBeginRun()+":"+foundTextSegment.getBeginText()+":"+foundTextSegment.getBeginChar());
System.out.println(foundTextSegment.getEndRun()+":"+foundTextSegment.getEndText()+":"+foundTextSegment.getEndChar());

   // maybe there is text before textToFind in begin run
   XWPFRun beginRun = paragraph.getRuns().get(foundTextSegment.getBeginRun());
   String textInBeginRun = beginRun.getText(foundTextSegment.getBeginText());
   String textBefore = textInBeginRun.substring(0, foundTextSegment.getBeginChar()); // we only need the text before

   // maybe there is text after textToFind in end run
   XWPFRun endRun = paragraph.getRuns().get(foundTextSegment.getEndRun());
   String textInEndRun = endRun.getText(foundTextSegment.getEndText());
   String textAfter = textInEndRun.substring(foundTextSegment.getEndChar() + 1); // we only need the text after

   if (foundTextSegment.getEndRun() == foundTextSegment.getBeginRun()) { 
    textInBeginRun = textBefore + replacement + textAfter; // if we have only one run, we need the text before, then the replacement, then the text after in that run
   } else {
    textInBeginRun = textBefore + replacement; // else we need the text before followed by the replacement in begin run
    endRun.setText(textAfter, foundTextSegment.getEndText()); // and the text after in end run
   }

   beginRun.setText(textInBeginRun, foundTextSegment.getBeginText());

   // runs between begin run and end run needs to be removed
   for (int runBetween = foundTextSegment.getEndRun() - 1; runBetween > foundTextSegment.getBeginRun(); runBetween--) {
    paragraph.removeRun(runBetween); // remove not needed runs
   }

  }
 }
 
 static List<XmlObject> getCTPObjects(XWPFDocument doc) {
  List<XmlObject> result = new ArrayList<XmlObject>();
  //create cursor selecting all paragraph elements  
  XmlCursor cursor = doc.getDocument().newCursor();
  cursor.selectPath("declare namespace w='http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main' .//*/w:p");  
  while(cursor.hasNextSelection()) {
   cursor.toNextSelection();
   XmlObject obj = cursor.getObject();    
   // add only if the paragraph contains at least a run containing text
   if (obj.selectPath("declare namespace w='http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main' ./w:r/w:t").length > 0) {
    result.add(obj);   
   }
  }
  return result;
 }
 
 static void traverseAllParagraphsAndReplace(XWPFDocument doc, Map<String, String> replacements) throws Exception { 
  //This gets all XWPFParagraph out od the stored XML and replaces 
  //first get all CTP objects
  List<XmlObject> allCTPObjects = getCTPObjects(doc);
  //then traverse them and create XWPFParagraphs from them and do the replacing
  for (XmlObject obj : allCTPObjects) {
   XWPFParagraph paragraph = null;
   if (obj instanceof CTP) {
    CTP p = (CTP)obj;
    paragraph = new XWPFParagraph(p, doc);
   } else {
    CTP p = CTP.Factory.parse(obj.xmlText());  
    paragraph = new XWPFParagraph(p, doc);
   }
   if (paragraph != null) {
    for (String textToFind : replacements.keySet()) {
     String replacement = replacements.get(textToFind);
     if (paragraph.getText().contains(textToFind)) replaceTextSegment(paragraph, textToFind, replacement);
    }
   }
   obj.set(paragraph.getCTP());
  }   
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("source.docx"));
  
  Map<String, String> replacements;
  replacements = new HashMap<String, String>();
  replacements.put("#name#", "Axel");
  replacements.put("#surename#", "Richter");

  traverseAllParagraphsAndReplace(doc, replacements);

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("result.docx");
  doc.write(out);
  out.close();
  doc.close();

 }
}
```

Comment: it give me "concurrent exception" but I resolve!